# Mongo Database insertion handle multiple collections

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework

I am inserting a document in Mongo database with insertOneAsync

await dbCollection.InsertOneAsync(entity);

After this action, I want to store the same document metadata ( id, createBy, timestamp) in a different collection ( metadata for dbCollection).

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: When inserting the data you can store the persisted document by returning the inserted document in your function then you can use that returned document or object's metadata to insert in another collection.

Comment: it should be a different insert

Comment: @AjajAli I am using repository pattern with an entity to insert. Should I use another repository to store metadata after the main document insertion